# How to get rid of boxing and unboxing in functional programing?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

says that we want to filter out all the odd one in a list.

```
odd' (i,n) = odd i
unbox (i,n) = n

f :: [Int] -> [Int]
f lst = map unbox $ filter odd' $ zip [1..] lst

*Main> f [1,2,3,4]
[1,3]
```

it has the unpleasant boxing and unboxing.

can we change the way we think this problem and eliminate boxing and unboxing?

@user3237465  list comprehension is indeed a good way of thinking this sort of problem.
as well as function composition. well, I think we won't get rid of "wrapping the original list to [(index,value)] form and then unwrap it" without writing a special form like @Carsten König provided.

Or have a function that give out one value's index given the list and the value. like `filter (odd . getindex) xs`

and maybe that's why clojure made it's pattern matching strong enough to get value in complex structure.

Comment: I don't see why this is unpleasant or why you would want to eliminate it. I think it's an elegant solution.

Comment: when I need to change it. the box and unbox part need to change together.when the call chain grows, it may involve more functions,[maybe by then i need to refine the data structure to some record?]

Comment: If you write a special function, you have to throw it away and replace it with a completely different function. If you compose your function out of smaller functions, you can change or replace those smaller parts. This can't be worse than writing a special function, but it can be *much* better.

Answer (score 4):

you can always rewrite the function if you want - this comes to mind:

```
odds :: [a] -> [a]
odds (x:_:xs) = x : odds xs
odds [x]      = [x]
odds _        = []
```

aside from this both you don't need `odd'` and `unbox`:

- `odd'` is just `odd . fst`
- `unbox` is just `snd`

Comment: some the `odds` function use a recursive jump one position to implement this thus avoid boxing and unboxing. Is that the only way? I'm wondering. I mean. would map/filter (see the input as a whole) always lead to boxing and unboxing? and i do did forget about `snd`

Comment: no there are surely lot's of ways - what are your concerns with this? Performance?

Comment: boxing and unboxing just doesn't feels right. code became steered together.  they need to be modified together. the `odds` way is great for this problem. what if we need filter out position according to given indexes.

Comment: It's just the opposite. `odds` is a special wrench that only works with this one particular type of nut. `map`, `filter`, and `zip` are adjustable wrenches that can be used together or separately in many combinations to solve many problems. To filter based on given indexes, you can just replace the given `filter odd'` with `filter (flip elem indexes . fst)`.

Comment: yeah you are right of course - not saying that it's a better method to *reinvent the wheel* in this special case here - btw: instead of `flip elem indexes` you could do ``(`elem` indexes)`` which reads nicer IMHO

Comment: @CarstenKönig  Yes, but the backticks broke the formatting for me and I am not as smart as you to figure out the escaping. ;)

Comment: @ReinHenrichs you can use use double and tripple backticks to get them in    (well failed myself - but you see it in my comment - I used double there)

Comment: I used this: ``` ``(`elem` indexes)`` ```

Answer (score 2):

You can write this as

```
f xs = [x | (i, x) <- zip [0..] xs, even i]
```

or

```
f = snd . foldr (\x ~(o, e) -> (e, x : o)) ([], [])
```

or

```
import Data.Either
f = lefts . zipWith ($) (cycle [Left, Right])
```